# .NET Socketserver max concurrent connections and max value for backlog

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets, scalability

I am currently working on a .NET c# socket server which should be able to scale upto 100K concurrent connections. I am using the socketasynceventargs class and the pattern mentioned [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socketasynceventargs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) . correct me if I am wrong but I understand that maintaining 100K concurrent connections is different from 100K client hitting the socket server at the exact same time. my question is how many connections can I make simultaneously? is this dependent on the socket backlog variable? if so what is the max backlog value i can set?

Thanks in advance

Comment: 100K connections on the same machine? with which throughput?

Comment: yes i want to check how much a single server can handle before we start scaling. my senario is the 100K clients would connect and send a message of about the size of 200-300 bytes. the server responds and sends an ack message and the client sends another message(this cycle repeats 10 time)

Comment: the 10 times is just a test senario. in realtime it could be just 1 or 50 etc

Comment: 1 or 50 per second, right?

Comment: the idea is the client should send all its messages one after the other as it gets the ack from the server after each message it sends the next message and closes the connection after all messages are sent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am currently working on a .NET c# socket server which should be able to scale upto 100K concurrent connections.

Last time I tested this on Win7 this was an easy goal to reach. The number of connections seems to be limited by memory usage.

> I am using the socketasynceventargs class and the pattern mentioned here.

This pattern is used to have a very high frequency of calls. It is not useful to maintain a high number of connections because it uses more memory than a simple `BeginRead` call that is outstanding. Always ask *why* and don't just copy sample code. Most sample code about sockets is horribly wrong, even on MSDN.

Have a single BeginRead call outstanding per socket. Until a read call is completed the memory buffer given to it is pinned. This causes GC problems. Either use one big preallocated buffer (64MB or so) or read only one byte at first. Only when that one byte read completes you read the rest with a bigger buffer.

> correct me if I am wrong but I understand that maintaining 100K concurrent connections is different from 100K client hitting the socket server at the exact same time.

Not sure I understand. 100k clients coming in in the same millisecond would be hard to handle while maintaining 100k connections that have been established over the course of seconds is much easier.

> my question is how many connections can I make simultaneously?

Test that and expect to find a high number. Watch your RAM usage.

> is this dependent on the socket backlog variable?

That is for outstanding connections that have not been handed to the application. It is mostly meaningless in practice because an app should have a fast accept loop immediately accepting anything.

> if so what is the max backlog value i can set?

Set the default.